How to connect to Strapi project created in railway from my terminal
I've created a Strapi project in Railway which works fine and it's in production. Railway created the url to access strapi and also de database base with Postgres. Everything works fine but how do I connect to the project from my terminal ?
The project isn't in local but in production because it was created directly from Railway. I mean, Railway gave me this url https://strapi-production-ec40.up.railway.app/ where is the strapi but, how do I connect from my terminal ?
I`ve tried ssh connection and railway cli but without no success.
